# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in Turborepo package

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, monorepo, turborepo

I have a typescript "test" package in turborepo and it imports and exports typescript function.

Since it is turborepo, its get copied to node_modules/test.

When i try to run `import {func} from "test"`. It gives me this error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.`
Ts config of test package is.

```
{
    "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": ".",
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```

Nodemon config of this node app

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "ext": "ts,mjs,js,json,graphql",
  "exec": "tsc && node ./dist/index.js",
  "legacyWatch": true
}
```

But when i try to import same thing in nextjs project with this included in config.

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['test'])
```

It works perfectly fine.

It looks to me that on node server side. When i am including that .ts from node_modules. Its not getting transpiled.

Any way to solve this?

I also tried building the package using tsc but it doesn't seem ideal to keep dist folder inside package.

Comment: It also works if i do npm run build on package. but the problem with it is that it requires generated dist folder to remain in package folder. How to make dist folder available in node_modules without publishing it on npm?

Comment: it can be too many reasons. Instead of making people guess, you should be sharing https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"type": "module"` to make import work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#type-in-packagejson-and-new-extensions

Comment: Did add type="module". getting same error

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

packages/test/package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess tsc ",
    "postinstall": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsc-watch": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for the **node** server, I use `ts-node --transpile-only index.ts` and it works with `.ts` files perfectly.